# Adding image upload to the plugin edit dialog in DjangoCMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I am new to Django CMS and am trying to build a plugin for a [hero section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image) (something like [this](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/hero/1.jpg)). I want to enable content managers to change the image of the hero section. I managed to add a text input to put the image's URL by using CharField in the model but looking of a way to allow image upload. This is the current state for reference:

[image: dajngoCMS plugin parameters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `FilerImageField` would fit the bill nicely:

```
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField

class TestModel(ModelClass):
    hero_image = FilerImageField(null=True, blank=True, related_name="page_hero_image", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```